# Will a pointer that has been added to a repeated field be deleted automatically?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Assume in Google Protobuf I have this message defined:

```
message address
{
    String street = 1;
    String name = 2;
}

message address_list
{
    repeated address addrs = 1;
}
```

And I will add addresses to an address list that have been allocated:

```
protobuf::address_list addrs;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
{
    protobuf::address *addr = addrs.add_addrs();
    addr->set_street("foo");
    addr->set_name("bar");
}
```

Who will be responsible for deleting the objects that have been created with new? I know that if you use a `set_allocated` function that protobuf will take care of deletion unless you call `release`, but how is it with repeated fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `new` with protobufs, it's generally not what you want. As written, you're leaking memory.

Furthermore, your code won't compile as written. Here is [the spec for repeated fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#repeatedmessage), but in short, to add elements in a loop like that, you should have code like the following:

```
protobuf::address_list addrs;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // This is a non-owning pointer. No delete necessary.
    protobuf::address *addr = addrs.add_addr();
    addr->set_street("foo");
    addr->set_name("bar");
}
```

Comment: thanks. ive written it from memory as a small example. So if I understand you correctly, then using the method shown by you, I will not need to `delete` the pointer to the addr.

Answer (score 2):

> Who will be responsible for deleting the objects that have been created with new?

Whoever created the object using `new`.

You created the object using `new`, so you are responsible for deleting it.

> I know that if you use a `set_allocated` function that protobuf will take care of deletion unless you call `release`

Correct. If you transfer ownership of the pointer to somewhere else, then the responsibility of deletion goes with the ownership. If you don't transfer the ownership (as in the example program), then the responsibility remains on you. If you don't delete it, then the memory leaks.